# Converting JFrame to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I currently have written some Java Swing using a `JFrame` and it works fine.

But now I need to use multiple screens and they are done using `cardlayouts`.

So i need to convert my `JFrame` to `JPanel`. Currently I have this line for my `JFrame`

```
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(c4Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But if I convert `mainFrame` to `JPanel` I cant use `getContentPane()` IDE tells me to use `getRootPane()`

but I get error on this line

```
mainPanel.getRootPane().add(c4Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't have `getContentPane` or `getRootPane`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: There are many differences between a `JFrame` and `JPanel` kindly get hold of a good book and go through it before asking questions.

Comment: I know there is difference between two, hence trying to convert between the two. Sorry if i wasnt clear

Comment: @Blip *"get hold of a good book"*  That is ***so*** last millennium!  I prefer the (online) [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree with you completely.

Comment: @user21902195 If you know the differences between the two, then could you explain how you could even think of calling `JPanel.getContentPane()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mainPanel.getRootPane().add(c4Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Should just be:

```
mainPanel.add(c4Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The code:

```
mainFrame.getContentPane()
```

..is simply returning a container which itself has an `add()` method, and the `getContentPane()` part has been unnecessary for some time.

Comment: I tried this `mainPanel.add(c4Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);` but i got this `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Has `c4Panel` been created?  Has `mainPanel` been created?  Answer in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Bluntly speaking though, solving a `NullPointerException` or understanding an IDE error message are things that a programmer should be used to *before* trying to make GUIs, which is quite an advanced topic.

Comment: yeah i m confused when i am getting it. `NullPointerException` I will search more. It works fine with JFrame, breaks with JPanel. Thanks for the help thought. 

Confirming that I was on the right track